# Recompiling FreeBSD-10 release from SVN source

Tags: bsd, freebsd

I run 10.0-RELEASE on my server and I'm wondering something.

If I do buildworld with official source from svn, will i be able to use freebsd-update to upgrade in the future or I have to settle with one of those two methods (binary or src) of upgrading?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got answer on project's IRC:

> **xmj**: building the base from sources will force you to keep rebuilding
>   it from source

Answer (score 0):

`portsnap` and `freebsd-update` will both install new ports tree and base installations (respectively); but can only update installs that those tools put in place. You can use `freebsd-update` to upgrade to a new installation, but you can not use it's `update` feature on a base built from source.